# Place view elements in circular manner using custom relative layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

In android there are different type of Layouts LinearLayout will place the items Linearly(Horizontal/Vertical). Where RelativeLayout can do better and can place items relative to each other items.

By Overiding the RelaiveLayout I want to create a Layout which draw elements in circular manner (as shown in picture). I am able to do this using code snippet here http://developer.samsung.com/android/samples-4

But it is creating the whole layout from java code only, so if i need to make some complex layouts which have this circle as an element in the Layout, It will make me crazy becuase I have to write a lot of code.

I want to do it in a simpler way, so that I can use the same concept in XMLs layouts.
Can anyone who experts in Making custom layouts suggest me how can I achieve the same. I want something like, I have a layout file

And from java code i will get that CircleLayout using id and Set into an Object of CircleLayout class. Now there should be some functions written in CircleLayout class using them I can do the modification in Layout like

```
  CircleLayout circle= (CircleLayout)findviewById(R.id.circle);
  circle.setRadiusOfLargestRing(20);
  circle.setNumberOfRings(6);
  //Define any type of view form java
  View v1 =new View(Context);
  circle.setCenteralView(v1);
  View v2 =new View(Context);
  circle.addElementOnrings(ringNumber, v2)
  ..so on
```

I want maximum three rings, I have no problem if the rings formed from drawable resounce(like three rings already placed in drawable folder).

and then we can set listeners to each view inserted in to the ring.
My layout should be smart enough to place the views in the in ring in a way shown in picture .

I will be glad If someone can help me to develop a library so others also can take benefits of the same.

I am ready to write whole code if someone can guide me.

[image]

Comment: hint: extend ViewGroup and override onLayout and onMeasure methods, see how it is done in other layouts e.g. LinearLayout

Comment: @pskink it will be really helpful if you can give some sort of sample code reference or any library code on github using the concept you shared.

Comment: see LinearLayout sources http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/LinearLayout.java

Comment: A little late, but maybe this will be useful for others : http://www.parleys.com/play/514892280364bc17fc56c0e2/chapter39/about

Comment: thanks @Raghuveer for sharing but it was not what i am looking for.